# An Issue having multiple SELECTs used in global ORDER clause

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, union

I need to combine the Five SQL result sets, taking Seven tables at a time by using UNION set operator

I used to get the error code from the tables: 'team', 'user_notifications', 'match_notifications' while executing the query from the `ORDER` clause

```
Error Code: 1250
Table 'team' from one of the SELECTs cannot be used in global ORDER clause
Table 'user_notifications' from one of the SELECTs cannot be used in global ORDER clause
Table 'match_notifications' from one of the SELECTs cannot be used in global ORDER clause
```

Here goes the SQL query

```
(SELECT
  `team`.`Team_ID`,
  `team_member`.`IsNotified`,
  `team_member`.`Team_Member_ID`,
  `team`.`Team_Name`,
  `team`.`Team_Logo`
FROM
  `team_member`
  LEFT JOIN `team`
    ON (
      `team_member`.`Team_ID` = `team`.`Team_ID`
    )
  LEFT JOIN `users`
    ON (
      `users`.`ID` = `team_member`.`Team_User_ID`
    )
WHERE `team_member`.`Team_User_ID` = '1'
  AND `team`.`Founder_ID` NOT IN
  (SELECT
    `team`.`Founder_ID`
  FROM
    `team`
  WHERE `team`.`Founder_ID` = '1'))
UNION
(SELECT
  ID,
  online_timestamp,
  username,
  online_timestamp,
  username,
  avatar
FROM
  users
WHERE users.ID IN
  (SELECT
    userid
  FROM
    user_friends
  WHERE STATUS = '1'
    AND `friendid` = '1') -- LIMIT 3 OFFSET 0 
)
UNION
(SELECT
  `user_notifications`.`notifi_id`,
  `users`.`ID`,
  `user_notifications`.`message`
FROM
  user_notifications
  JOIN users
    ON (
      user_notifications.fromid = users.ID
    )
WHERE user_notifications.status = '0'
  AND user_notifications.userid = '1')
UNION
(SELECT
  `team`.`Team_ID`,
  `team`.`Founder_ID`,
  `team`.`Team_Logo`,
  `team`.`Team_Name`,
  `team_member`.`IsFounder`,
  `team_member`.`IsTeamLead`,
  `team_member`.`Team_ID`,
  `team_member`.`Team_UserName`,
  `team_member`.`Team_User_ID`,
  `match_notifications`.`accept_status`,
  `match_notifications`.`game_match_id`,
  `match_notifications`.`message`,
  `match_notifications`.`notification_status`,
  `match_notifications`.`team_1_id`,
  `match_notifications`.`team_2_id`,
  `match_notifications`.`timestamp`,
  `teams_game_match`.`accept`,
  `teams_game_match`.`game_date`,
  `teams_game_match`.`game_id`,
  `teams_game_match`.`team_1_name`,
  `teams_game_match`.`team_2_name`,
  `teams_game_match`.`game_name`
FROM
  `team`
  INNER JOIN `team_member`
    ON (
      `team`.`Team_ID` = `team_member`.`Team_ID`
    )
  INNER JOIN `match_notifications`
    ON (
      `team`.`Team_ID` = `match_notifications`.`team_2_id`
    )
  INNER JOIN `teams_game_match`
    ON (
      `teams_game_match`.`game_match_id` = `match_notifications`.`game_match_id`
    )
WHERE `team_member`.`Team_User_ID` = '1'
  OR `team`.`Founder_ID` = '1')
UNION
(SELECT
  `match_notifications`.`notification_id`,
  `match_notifications`.`notification_status`
FROM
  `match_notifications`
  INNER JOIN `team_member`
    ON (
      `team_member`.`Team_ID` = `match_notifications`.`team_1_id`
    )
  INNER JOIN `teams_game_match`
    ON (
      `teams_game_match`.`game_match_id` = `match_notifications`.`game_match_id`
    )
  INNER JOIN `team`
    ON (
      `match_notifications`.`team_1_id` = `team`.`Team_ID`
    )
WHERE `match_notifications`.`accept_status` != '0'
  AND `team_member`.`IsTeamLead` = 1
  AND (
    `team_member`.`Team_User_ID` = '1'
    OR `team`.`Founder_ID` = '1'
  ))
ORDER BY 
`team`.`Team_ID`,
`user_notifications`.`notifi_id`,
`match_notifications`.`game_match_id`,
`match_notifications`.`notification_id` 
DESC LIMIT 15 OFFSET 0
```

Any advice for fixing the Error Code: 1250 or

How should I need to achieve in combining the above four SQL other than using `UNION` set operator?

Comment: There's something seriously wrong with your query - you union multiple tables, with completely different number of columns (and I sense also with very different content), and then outside of it you order it. In short what you do is: ```(SELECT a,b,c FROM A) UNION (SELECT d,e,f,g FROM B) UNION (SELECT h,i from C) ORDER BY j,k,l``` - please check your brackets I feel like you need major reorganization in there...

Comment: What about sub-queries and Joins. How do we alias sub-queries and Joins as a single table? Will you explain taking any above two SQL. As I'm not getting how should we need to group Do you mean to say `SELECT x.a, y.b FROM (SELECT * from a) as x, (SELECT * FROM b) as y` @GrzegorzSkibinski

Comment: Hm, you mean like this: ```(SELECT
  t.Team_ID,
  t_m.IsNotified,
  t_m.Team_Member_ID,
  t.Team_Name,
  t.Team_Logo
FROM
  team_member t_m
  LEFT JOIN team t
    ON t_m.Team_ID = t.Team_ID
  LEFT JOIN users usr
    ON usr.ID = t_m.Team_User_ID
WHERE t_m.Team_User_ID = '1'
  AND t.Founder_ID NOT IN
  (SELECT
    Founder_ID
  FROM
    team
  WHERE Founder_ID = '1'))```

Answer (score 0):

Use alias for all of these 
`team`.`Team_ID` as C1
`user_notifications`.`notifi_id` as C2
`match_notifications`.`game_match_id` as C3
`match_notifications`.`notification_id` as C4

then 
ORDER BY 
C1,
C2,
C3,
C4 
DESC LIMIT 15 OFFSET 0

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I figured out the semantic structure of the SQL.
I have used `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` clause, set to 3 which sets the offset to 0. Thereby, selecting utmost 3 different results set limiting up to 15 used in every 5 queries. But not exactly 15, since data may or may not be present with each of the result set limiting to maximum 3

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  (
    (SELECT
      t.Team_ID AS j_Team_ID,
      t_m.IsNotified AS j_IsNotified,
      t_m.Team_Member_ID AS j_Team_Member_ID,
      t.Team_Name AS j_Team_Name,
      t.Team_Logo AS j_Team_Logo,
      NULL AS un_notifi_id,
      NULL AS un_id,
      NULL AS un_message,
      NULL AS un_avatar,
      NULL AS un_online_timestamp,
      NULL AS un_username,
      NULL AS uf_id,
      NULL AS uf_online_timestamp,
      NULL AS uf_username,
      NULL AS uf_avatar,
      NULL AS mn_Team_ID,
      NULL AS mn_Founder_ID,
      NULL AS mn_Team_Logo,
      NULL AS mn_Team_Name,
      NULL AS mn_IsTeamLead,
      NULL AS mn_Team_UserName,
      NULL AS mn_Team_User_ID,
      NULL AS mn_accept_status,
      NULL AS mn_game_match_id,
      NULL AS mn_message,
      NULL AS mn_notification_status,
      NULL AS mn_team_1_id,
      NULL AS mn_team_2_id,
      NULL AS mn_timestamp,
      NULL AS mn_accept,
      NULL AS mn_game_date,
      NULL AS mn_game_id,
      NULL AS mn_team_1_name,
      NULL AS mn_team_2_name,
      NULL AS mn_teams_game_match,
      NULL AS mn_notification_id,
      NULL AS pm_Team_ID,
      NULL AS pm_Founder_ID,
      NULL AS pm_Team_Logo,
      NULL AS pm_Team_Name,
      NULL AS pm_IsTeamLead,
      NULL AS pm_game_match_id,
      NULL AS pm_team_1_id,
      NULL AS pm_team_2_id,
      NULL AS pm_timestamp,
      NULL AS pm_accept,
      NULL AS pm_game_date,
      NULL AS pm_team_1_name,
      NULL AS pm_team_2_name,
      NULL AS pm_game_name,
      NULL AS pm_notification_status,
      NULL AS pm_notification_id,
      NULL AS pm_message
    FROM
      team_member t_m
      LEFT JOIN team t
        ON t_m.Team_ID = t.Team_ID
      LEFT JOIN users usr
        ON usr.ID = t_m.Team_User_ID
    WHERE t_m.Team_User_ID = '1'
      AND t.Founder_ID NOT IN
      (SELECT
        Founder_ID
      FROM
        team
      WHERE Founder_ID = '1')
    ORDER BY `t`.`Team_ID` DESC-- limit 0,3
    )
    UNION
    (SELECT
      NULL AS j_Team_ID,
      NULL AS j_IsNotified,
      NULL AS j_Team_Member_ID,
      NULL AS j_Team_Name,
      NULL AS j_Team_Logo,
      `un`.`notifi_id` AS un_notifi_id,
      `users`.`ID` AS un_id,
      `un`.`message` AS un_message,
      `users`.`avatar` AS un_avatar,
      `users`.`online_timestamp` AS un_online_timestamp,
      `users`.`username` AS un_username,
      NULL AS uf_id,
      NULL AS uf_online_timestamp,
      NULL AS uf_username,
      NULL AS uf_avatar,
      NULL AS mn_Team_ID,
      NULL AS mn_Founder_ID,
      NULL AS mn_Team_Logo,
      NULL AS mn_Team_Name,
      NULL AS mn_IsTeamLead,
      NULL AS mn_Team_UserName,
      NULL AS mn_Team_User_ID,
      NULL AS mn_accept_status,
      NULL AS mn_game_match_id,
      NULL AS mn_message,
      NULL AS mn_notification_status,
      NULL AS mn_team_1_id,
      NULL AS mn_team_2_id,
      NULL AS mn_timestamp,
      NULL AS mn_accept,
      NULL AS mn_game_date,
      NULL AS mn_game_id,
      NULL AS mn_team_1_name,
      NULL AS mn_team_2_name,
      NULL AS mn_teams_game_match,
      NULL AS mn_notification_id,
      NULL AS pm_Team_ID,
      NULL AS pm_Founder_ID,
      NULL AS pm_Team_Logo,
      NULL AS pm_Team_Name,
      NULL AS pm_IsTeamLead,
      NULL AS pm_game_match_id,
      NULL AS pm_team_1_id,
      NULL AS pm_team_2_id,
      NULL AS pm_timestamp,
      NULL AS pm_accept,
      NULL AS pm_game_date,
      NULL AS pm_team_1_name,
      NULL AS pm_team_2_name,
      NULL AS pm_game_name,
      NULL AS pm_notification_status,
      NULL AS pm_notification_id,
      NULL AS pm_message
    FROM
      user_notifications un
      JOIN users
        ON (un.fromid = users.ID)
    WHERE un.status = '0'
      AND un.userid = '1'
    ORDER BY `un`.`notifi_id` DESC-- limit 3
    )
    UNION
    (SELECT
      NULL AS j_Team_ID,
      NULL AS j_IsNotified,
      NULL AS j_Team_Member_ID,
      NULL AS j_Team_Name,
      NULL AS j_Team_Logo,
      NULL AS un_notifi_id,
      NULL AS un_id,
      NULL AS un_message,
      NULL AS un_avatar,
      NULL AS un_online_timestamp,
      NULL AS un_username,
      ID AS uf_id,
      online_timestamp AS uf_online_timestamp,
      username AS uf_username,
      avatar AS uf_avatar,
      NULL AS mn_Team_ID,
      NULL AS mn_Founder_ID,
      NULL AS mn_Team_Logo,
      NULL AS mn_Team_Name,
      NULL AS mn_IsTeamLead,
      NULL AS mn_Team_UserName,
      NULL AS mn_Team_User_ID,
      NULL AS mn_accept_status,
      NULL AS mn_game_match_id,
      NULL AS mn_message,
      NULL AS mn_notification_status,
      NULL AS mn_team_1_id,
      NULL AS mn_team_2_id,
      NULL AS mn_timestamp,
      NULL AS mn_accept,
      NULL AS mn_game_date,
      NULL AS mn_game_id,
      NULL AS mn_team_1_name,
      NULL AS mn_team_2_name,
      NULL AS mn_teams_game_match,
      NULL AS mn_notification_id,
      NULL AS pm_Team_ID,
      NULL AS pm_Founder_ID,
      NULL AS pm_Team_Logo,
      NULL AS pm_Team_Name,
      NULL AS pm_IsTeamLead,
      NULL AS pm_game_match_id,
      NULL AS pm_team_1_id,
      NULL AS pm_team_2_id,
      NULL AS pm_timestamp,
      NULL AS pm_accept,
      NULL AS pm_game_date,
      NULL AS pm_team_1_name,
      NULL AS pm_team_2_name,
      NULL AS pm_game_name,
      NULL AS pm_notification_status,
      NULL AS pm_notification_id,
      NULL AS pm_message
    FROM
      users
    WHERE users.ID IN
      (SELECT
        userid
      FROM
        user_friends
      WHERE STATUS = '1'
        AND `friendid` = '1')
    ORDER BY uf_online_timestamp DESC-- limit 0,3
    )
    UNION
    (SELECT
      NULL AS j_Team_ID,
      NULL AS j_IsNotified,
      NULL AS j_Team_Member_ID,
      NULL AS j_Team_Name,
      NULL AS j_Team_Logo,
      NULL AS un_notifi_id,
      NULL AS un_id,
      NULL AS un_message,
      NULL AS un_avatar,
      NULL AS un_online_timestamp,
      NULL AS un_username,
      NULL AS uf_id,
      NULL AS uf_online_timestamp,
      NULL AS uf_username,
      NULL AS uf_avatar,
      `team`.`Team_ID` AS mn_Team_ID,
      `team`.`Founder_ID` AS mn_Founder_ID,
      `team`.`Team_Logo` AS mn_Team_Logo,
      `team`.`Team_Name` AS mn_Team_Name,
      `team_member`.`IsTeamLead` AS mn_IsTeamLead,
      `team_member`.`Team_UserName` AS mn_Team_UserName,
      `team_member`.`Team_User_ID` AS mn_Team_User_ID,
      `match_notifications`.`accept_status` AS mn_accept_status,
      `match_notifications`.`game_match_id` AS mn_game_match_id,
      `match_notifications`.`message` AS mn_message,
      `match_notifications`.`notification_status` AS mn_notification_status,
      `match_notifications`.`team_1_id` AS mn_team_1_id,
      `match_notifications`.`team_2_id` AS mn_team_2_id,
      `match_notifications`.`timestamp` AS mn_timestamp,
      `teams_game_match`.`accept` AS mn_accept,
      `teams_game_match`.`game_date` AS mn_game_date,
      `teams_game_match`.`game_id` AS mn_game_id,
      `teams_game_match`.`team_1_name` AS mn_team_1_name,
      `teams_game_match`.`team_2_name` AS mn_team_2_name,
      `teams_game_match`.`game_name` AS mn_teams_game_match,
      `match_notifications`.`notification_id` AS mn_notification_id,
      NULL AS pm_Team_ID,
      NULL AS pm_Founder_ID,
      NULL AS pm_Team_Logo,
      NULL AS pm_Team_Name,
      NULL AS pm_IsTeamLead,
      NULL AS pm_game_match_id,
      NULL AS pm_team_1_id,
      NULL AS pm_team_2_id,
      NULL AS pm_timestamp,
      NULL AS pm_accept,
      NULL AS pm_game_date,
      NULL AS pm_team_1_name,
      NULL AS pm_team_2_name,
      NULL AS pm_game_name,
      NULL AS pm_notification_status,
      NULL AS pm_notification_id,
      NULL AS pm_message
    FROM
      `match_notifications`
      INNER JOIN `team_member`
        ON (
          `team_member`.`Team_ID` = `match_notifications`.`team_1_id`
        )
      INNER JOIN `teams_game_match`
        ON (
          `teams_game_match`.`game_match_id` = `match_notifications`.`game_match_id`
        )
      INNER JOIN `team`
        ON (
          `match_notifications`.`team_1_id` = `team`.`Team_ID`
        )
    WHERE `match_notifications`.`accept_status` != '0'
      AND `team_member`.`IsTeamLead` = 1
      AND (
        `team_member`.`Team_User_ID` = '1'
        OR `team`.`Founder_ID` = '1'
      )
    ORDER BY `match_notifications`.`notification_id` DESC-- LIMIT 3 OFFSET 0
    )
    UNION
    (SELECT
      NULL AS j_Team_ID,
      NULL AS j_IsNotified,
      NULL AS j_Team_Member_ID,
      NULL AS j_Team_Name,
      NULL AS j_Team_Logo,
      NULL AS un_notifi_id,
      NULL AS un_id,
      NULL AS un_message,
      NULL AS un_avatar,
      NULL AS un_online_timestamp,
      NULL AS un_username,
      NULL AS uf_id,
      NULL AS uf_online_timestamp,
      NULL AS uf_username,
      NULL AS uf_avatar,
      NULL AS mn_Team_ID,
      NULL AS mn_Founder_ID,
      NULL AS mn_Team_Logo,
      NULL AS mn_Team_Name,
      NULL AS mn_IsTeamLead,
      NULL AS mn_Team_UserName,
      NULL AS mn_Team_User_ID,
      NULL AS mn_accept_status,
      NULL AS mn_game_match_id,
      NULL AS mn_message,
      NULL AS mn_notification_status,
      NULL AS mn_team_1_id,
      NULL AS mn_team_2_id,
      NULL AS mn_timestamp,
      NULL AS mn_accept,
      NULL AS mn_game_date,
      NULL AS mn_game_id,
      NULL AS mn_team_1_name,
      NULL AS mn_team_2_name,
      NULL AS mn_teams_game_match,
      NULL AS mn_notification_id,
      `team`.`Team_ID` AS pm_Team_ID,
      `team`.`Founder_ID` AS pm_Founder_ID,
      `team`.`Team_Logo` AS pm_Team_Logo,
      `team`.`Team_Name` AS pm_Team_Name,
      `team_member`.`IsTeamLead` AS pm_IsTeamLead,
      `match_notifications`.`game_match_id` AS pm_game_match_id,
      `match_notifications`.`team_1_id` AS pm_team_1_id,
      `match_notifications`.`team_2_id` AS pm_team_2_id,
      `match_notifications`.`timestamp` AS pm_timestamp,
      `teams_game_match`.`accept` AS pm_accept,
      `teams_game_match`.`game_date` AS pm_game_date,
      `teams_game_match`.`team_1_name` AS pm_team_1_name,
      `teams_game_match`.`team_2_name` AS pm_team_2_name,
      `teams_game_match`.`game_name` AS pm_game_name,
      `match_notifications`.`notification_status` AS pm_notification_status,
      `match_notifications`.`notification_id` AS pm_notification_id,
      `match_notifications`.`message` AS pm_message
    FROM
      `team`
      INNER JOIN `team_member`
        ON (
          `team`.`Team_ID` = `team_member`.`Team_ID`
        )
      INNER JOIN `match_notifications`
        ON (
          `team`.`Team_ID` = `match_notifications`.`team_2_id`
        )
      INNER JOIN `teams_game_match`
        ON (
          `teams_game_match`.`game_match_id` = `match_notifications`.`game_match_id` AND `team_member`.`IsTeamLead` = 1 AND `teams_game_match`.`accept` = 0
        )
    WHERE `team_member`.`Team_User_ID` = '1'
      OR `team`.`Founder_ID` = '1'
    ORDER BY `match_notifications`.`game_match_id` DESC-- LIMIT 3 OFFSET 0 
    )
  ) A
```

---

If anyone knows better solutions than what I had posted, you can post your answer or leave a constructive criticizing comment which is always accepted

Comment: Wow, that's a very long ... How does this output look like?